# Livewire is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, nginx, laravel-livewire

I am having an issue deploying my Laravel Livewire project to the server. The issue is that livewire.js file is not accessible and showing an error in the console

```
Livewire is not defined
```

My server environment is LNMP. I am using Nginx instead of apache. There is an alternate way to fix this by publishing livewire which copies files from vendor folder to resources folder. By you have to maintain js files yourself after that and i don't want to do that.
It may be caused by Nginx by blocking js response files, How can I fix this

This is my nginx config file

```
user  www www;
worker_processes auto;
error_log  /www/wwwlogs/nginx_error.log  crit;
pid        /www/server/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 51200;

events
    {
        use epoll;
        worker_connections 51200;
        multi_accept on;
    }

http
    {
#AAPANEL_FASTCGI_CONF_BEGIN
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_path /dev/shm/nginx-cache/wp levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:100m inactive=60m max_size=1g;
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
#AAPANEL_FASTCGI_CONF_END

        include       mime.types;
        #include luawaf.conf;

        include proxy.conf;

        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 512;
        client_header_buffer_size 32k;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
        client_max_body_size 50m;

        sendfile   on;
        tcp_nopush on;

        keepalive_timeout 60;

        tcp_nodelay on;

        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 64k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 128k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length  1k;
        gzip_buffers     4 16k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        gzip_types     text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/css application/xml;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied   expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_disable   "MSIE [1-6]\.";

        limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=perip:10m;
        limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=perserver:10m;

        server_tokens off;
        access_log off;

server
    {
        listen 888;
        server_name phpmyadmin;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        root  /www/server/phpmyadmin;
            location ~ /tmp/ {
                return 403;
            }

        #error_page   404   /404.html;
        include enable-php.conf;

        location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
        {
            expires      30d;
        }

        location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
        {
            expires      12h;
        }

        location ~ /\.
        {
            deny all;
        }

        access_log  /www/wwwlogs/access.log;
    }
include /www/server/panel/vhost/nginx/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: Have you installed Livewire through composer in production, and then run `php artisan optimize:clear`?

Comment: What do you mean by production via composer?

Comment: Did you either upload the entire project with the vendor folder and all, or if you installed it via Git, then you have to do `composer install`. In either case you might have to do `php artisan optimize` to load the blade directives

Comment: ...yes, and the `/livewire/livewire.js` file is exposed via the LivewireServiceProvider, which is autoloaded by Composer. If the serviceprovider is not registered, it will not load that script. But if you haven't made Composer aware of that provider, it can't load it. So that *can* be one of the issues. https://github.com/livewire/livewire/blob/master/src/LivewireServiceProvider.php#L145 I really doubt its Ngnix blocking .js files, then you've done something weird with your config.

Comment: Doing `php artisan optimize` will mean that if the layout has been cached without the `@livewireScripts` directive, it will actually run the directive - which is where it actually loads in the `livewire.js` from the browser-point-of-view.

Comment: I tried that already. Caching is not the issue here

Answer (score 1):

livewire.js does not change as much, unless there is a change in composer.json regarding laravel-livewire package, i suggest you just publish your livewire.js file using

> php artisan livewire:publish --assets

And then adding auto publishing script

```
{
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi",
        "@php artisan vendor:publish --force --tag=livewire:assets --ansi"
    ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).